# How to position excel chart x axis text position c#

Tags: c#, excel, charts

i am developing a chart programmatically using c# and excel interop dll.

i have to develop this kind of char. here is the screen shot[image]

i almost done my job and my UI looks like 
[image]

just see the **arrow sign** i want to put that text at the right hand side like above chart but due to lack of knowledge i am getting trouble.

here i am giving my full code. please see to it and guide me what extra code i need to put to position that text. thanks

```
   Excel.Application xlApp ;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheetChart;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

    try
    {


        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        xlWorkSheet.Name = "Data";

        xlWorkSheetChart = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(2);
        xlWorkSheetChart.Name = "Chart";

        //add data 
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Date";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "2013 10 15";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "2013 10 16";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 1] = "2013 10 17";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 1] = "2013 10 18";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[6, 1] = "2013 10 21";

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "TOTAL No of jobs";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2] = "211";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 2] = "148";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 2] = "183";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 2] = "185";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[6, 2] = "180";

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "TOTAL Turnaround";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 3] = "76.03";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 3] = "36.27";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 3] = "32.38";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 3] = "64.62";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[6, 3] = "43.15";

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "TOTAL 1-day percentage";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 4] = "35.59";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 4] = "51.44";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 4] = "277.66";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 4] = "161.78";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[6, 4] = "314.39";

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "TOTAL hours";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 5] = "16042.33";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 5] = "5367.96";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 5] = "5925.54";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 5] = "11954.7";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[6, 5] = "7767";

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 6] = "Number of techs";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 6] = "37";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 6] = "19";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 6] = "18";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 6] = "20";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[6, 6] = "28";

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 7] = "Work hours/tech";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 7] = "8";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 7] = "8";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 7] = "8";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 7] = "8";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[6, 7] = "8";

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 8] = "Efficiency";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 8] = "0.7";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 8] = "0.7";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 8] = "0.7";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 8] = "0.7";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[6, 8] = "0.7";

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 9] = "Theoretical hours";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 9] = "207.2";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 9] = "106.4";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 9] = "100.8";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 9] = "112";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[6, 9] = "156.8";



        Excel.SeriesCollection seriesCollection;
        Excel.Series series1, series2, series3;

        Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheetChart.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(200, 80, 300, 250);
        Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
        chartPage.HasTitle = true;
        chartPage.ChartTitle.Text = "Daily Job History";
        myChart.Width = 500;
        chartPage.Legend.Position = XlLegendPosition.xlLegendPositionBottom;


        seriesCollection = (Excel.SeriesCollection)chartPage.SeriesCollection(Type.Missing);
        series1 = seriesCollection.NewSeries();
        series2 = seriesCollection.NewSeries();
        series3 = seriesCollection.NewSeries();

        series1.Name = "=Data!$B$1";
        series1.Values = "=Data!$B$2:$B$6";
        series1.ChartType = XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;

        series2.Name = "=Data!$C$1";
        series2.XValues = "=Data!$A$2:$A$6";
        series2.Values = "=Data!$C$2:$C$6";
        series2.ChartType = XlChartType.xlLineMarkers;

        series3.Name = "=Data!$D$1";
        series3.Values = "=Data!$D$2:$D$6";
        series3.ChartType = XlChartType.xlLineMarkers;

        Axis axis;
        axis = (Axis)chartPage.Axes(XlAxisType.xlCategory, XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
        axis.HasTitle = true;
        axis.AxisTitle.Text = "Right Side text";
        axis.HasMajorGridlines = false;
        axis.HasMinorGridlines = false;


        axis = (Axis)chartPage.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue, XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
        axis.HasTitle = true;
        axis.AxisTitle.Text = "Left Side text"; ;
        axis.HasMajorGridlines = true;
        axis.HasMinorGridlines = false;

        chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory).Select();
        chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory).TickLabels.Orientation = 35;

        string strpath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath.ToString() + "\\test.xls";

        if (File.Exists(strpath))
        {
            File.Delete(strpath);
        }


        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(strpath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook = null;
        xlApp.Quit();
        xlApp = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    }
    //releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
    //releaseObject(xlWorkSheetChart);
    //releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
    //releaseObject(xlApp);


    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to put this on the `XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary` axis not the `XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary`.

You also need to use `XlAxisType.xlValue` for the Y axis

```
Axis axis;
    axis = (Axis)chartPage.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue, XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary);
    axis.HasTitle = true;
    axis.AxisTitle.Text = "Right Side text";
    axis.HasMajorGridlines = false;
    axis.HasMinorGridlines = false;
```